# How to add 'odd' or 'even' class in each row of a Views Table output?

Tags: views, 8

I'd like to take advantage of Drupal's default CSS for even/odd rows in a table.
I use Views to list the content of a custom entity with 'Table' format.
I don't know where to put this setting...

Thanks in advance

P.-S. I use Drupal 8 (8.1.2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be related to Drupal, since you want to add classes to table rows, here is how you do it:

Copy the core/themes/classy/themplates/views/views-view-table.html.twig to your theme's template folder, and change the following lines (line 95):

```
  <tbody>
    {% for row in rows %}
      {% set parity = cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index0) %}
      <tr {{ row.attributes.addClass(parity) }}>
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks.  
Would like now to add my own CSS file to replace Drupal's default behavior.  
But I can't make it work!  

Tried to add `{{ attach_library('amap/myLibrary') }}` to 'amap_distributions_dates.html.twig' that is in 'templates' folder of my module.

Comment: I think maybe you should open another issue, but before that: 
1. Your code seems to be alright. Be sure that you have an "amap" module, where you have a amap.libraries.yml and you have a "myLibrary" root yaml key there.
2. Also clear cache, or turn off twig cache. Try to check, if you css is loaded or not.