# How do I add a specific class in a row of a table output depending on a field content?

Tags: views, 8

I use the Views module to list the content of a custom entity, using the *Table* format.
I'd like to add the *myClass* CSS class to each row where a given field is equal to zero.

How can I achieve this?

`Edit` I found out that I could use 'Rewrite results' (Overriding the output of a field with custom text) with twig.
For example:

```
{% if nombreproduits == '0' %}  
{{ '99/99/9999' }}  
{% else %}  
{{ datedistribution }}  
{% endif %}
```

How could I use that to add a class to the corresponding row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I made it work this way:

In Page>Format>Settings, I set 'Row class' to `"myClass"~{{ nombreproduits }}` where nombreproduits is the field to be checked equal to zero.
The result is something like `<tr class="myClass0">` in the corresponding rows (and, of course, myClass1, myClass2, etc. when nombreproduits = 1, 2 etc.).
Then, just have to add `tr.myClass0`to my custom CSS file...

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. You alter your view with a View hook and you add to the row class value your own class based on one of the field value
2. You use [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203642/how-to-add-odd-or-even-class-in-each-row-of-a-views-table-output) solution, and you can check with twig the actual row content and add a class based on that(use devel module and {{ kint(row) }} to understand how to reach the values you want)

Comment: Tried to use kint but, so far, without success. Will dig in...

Comment: Twig is heavily cached, you will have to turn that off, else you always will have to clear the cache with drush cr

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure to know where to put `{{ kint(row) }}`. In one field 'Rewrite results'? Elsewhere?

Comment: Well, you have a "for" loop {% for row in rows % }. You have to put it there. But you can try it anywhere to print out twig variables!